# ICS Timezone "Z" not working?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, time-zone, ics

I live in Seattle, so I'm on Pacific Time.

I have an ICS file which contains this event:

```
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTEND:20160309T050000
UID:worldt20-2016-03
DTSTAMP:20120315T170000Z
SUMMARY:Bangladesh v Netherlands
LOCATION:HPCA Stadium
DESCRIPTION:Bangladesh v Netherlands - Match 3
DTSTART:20160309T093000
END:VEVENT
```

So the DTSTART is showing 3/9/2016 at 9:30AM, but I'm not sure what timezone it's supposed to be in. If I add it to Outlook, it shows up on 3/9/2016 at 5:00AM. Where is it getting this value? I figured it's confused as to what timezone the DTSTART is in, so I added a "Z" on them, which is supposed to make it UTC, right? So now I have this:

```
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTEND:20160309T050000Z
UID:worldt20-2016-03
DTSTAMP:20120315T170000Z
SUMMARY:Bangladesh v Netherlands
LOCATION:HPCA Stadium
DESCRIPTION:Bangladesh v Netherlands - Match 3
DTSTART:20160309T093000Z
END:VEVENT
```

So I would assume that the DTSTART of 20160309T093000Z means 3/9/2016 at 9:30AM UTC, and since I'm in Seattle, when I open the file it should show up on 3/9/2016 at 1:30AM. So why is it showing up on 3/8/2016 at 9:00PM?

Comment: Just to understand.. Do you have any idea why DTEND always comes before DTSTART? (05:00 as opposed to 09:30)

Answer (score 0):

An educated guess: the pattern seems to be it's always subtracting 4:30h more than it should because DTEND comes before DTSTART (specifically 5:00 comes before 9:30 regardless of timezone and DTSTART-DTEND equals exactly 4:30h) so maybe it assumes the start & end times are reversed and therefore decides to show DTEND (you think you see DTSTART but you actually see DTEND)